# (udisks-error-quark, 0) error while trying to open my USB flash memory

Tags: filesystems, mount, usb-drive

I had an Ubuntu 22.04 running wth no problems but decided to change my SSD card and install the exact same Ubuntu on a new SSD. So I copied some important files into a USB flash memory and after it finished I checked to see if all files have been copied, so that was.

Then I changed the SSD and installed the same Ubuntu on the new SSD and tried the flash memory to reach my files but I get `unknown  (udisks-error-quark, 0)` error when I try to open the flash memory.

[image]

When I use `disks` to mount it:

[image]

Comment: You can try using Disks to repair the file system (select the partition and right-click).

Comment: @ChanganAuto: I can't see any repair option. I see format disk, create/restore disk image and benchmark options available.

Comment: It's not in the main menu. I specifically said "select the partition and right-click *the* partition (or click the double-cog button *under* the partition, then "repair filesystem".

Comment: I know it may sound unrealistic, but I had the same, and I just wanted to verify why that was happening. I connected the SSD to my other laptop (which runs Windows), and it opened it and then reconnected the SSD to my Ubuntu laptop again, and it worked again!

Answer (score 0):

***How to Fix “Wrong Fs Type, Bad Option, Bad Superblock” Error? / HDD not mounnting***

1. check which disk is not mounted

   ```shell
   lsblk -fape7
   ```
2. Now go to disks application and get the UUID of the unmounted disk
3. Go to the directory under which removable disks will usually be mounted

   ```shell
   cd /media/your_username/
   ```
4. Create a sub-directory there; you can choose any name you like

   ```shell
   mkdir whatever_name
   ```

   E.g. you can use the UUID and append a `1` to prevent name-conflicts (as in `3759B3CD711BFC691`)
5. Identify the device attributes

   ```shell
   blkid /dev/sda3
   ```
6. Modify the `fstab`:

   ```shell
   sudo nano /etc/fstab
   ```

   Example: (**Please enter tab after every column**)

   ```
   UUID=3759B3CD711BFC69 /media/3759B3CD711BFC691       ntfs    defaults        0       1    

   //  ^ newly entered unmounted disk UUID and followed by the newly created dir and mounted on it successfully

   // Do not change these
   UUID=f34c4f3c-5870-4bca-ba3b-cedc626f43f1       /       ext4    defaults        0       1
   UUID=4CF1-03CB  /boot/efi       vfat    defaults        0       1
   /swap.img       none    swap    sw      0       0
   ```
7. Save and exit

***RESULT***

- Before

  ```
  $lsblk -fape7

  NAME             FSTYPE FSVER LABEL   UUID                                 FSAVAIL FSUSE% MOUNTPOINTS
  /dev/sda                                                                                  
  └─/dev/sda1      ntfs         HDD 1TB 3759B3CD711BFC69                      (Not showing)   :(           
  /dev/nvme0n1                                                                              
  ├─/dev/nvme0n1p1 vfat   FAT32         4CF1-03CB                              63.5M    34% /run/timeshift/5619/restore/boot/efi
  │                                                                                         /boot/efi
  ├─/dev/nvme0n1p2                                                                          
  ├─/dev/nvme0n1p3 ntfs                 6800F31900F2ECC6                       59.5G    63% /media/hiranmay1000/6800F31900F2ECC61
  └─/dev/nvme0n1p4 ext4   1.0           f34c4f3c-5870-4bca-ba3b-cedc626f43f1   21.9G    65% /run/timeshift/5619/restore
                                                                                            /run/timeshift/5619/backup
                                                                                            /var/snap/firefox/common/host-hunspell
                                                                                            /
  ```
- After:

  ```shellsession
  $ lsblk -fape7

  NAME             FSTYPE FSVER LABEL   UUID                                 FSAVAIL FSUSE% MOUNTPOINTS
  /dev/sda                                                                                  
  └─/dev/sda1      ntfs         HDD 1TB 3759B3CD711BFC69                      862.5G     7% /media/3759B3CD711BFC691  <-(successfully mounted)  :)
  /dev/nvme0n1                                                                              
  ├─/dev/nvme0n1p1 vfat   FAT32         4CF1-03CB                              63.5M    34% /run/timeshift/5619/restore/boot/efi
  │                                                                                         /boot/efi
  ├─/dev/nvme0n1p2                                                                          
  ├─/dev/nvme0n1p3 ntfs                 6800F31900F2ECC6                       59.5G    63% /media/hiranmay1000/6800F31900F2ECC61
  └─/dev/nvme0n1p4 ext4   1.0           f34c4f3c-5870-4bca-ba3b-cedc626f43f1   21.9G    65% /run/timeshift/5619/restore
                                                                                            /run/timeshift/5619/backup
                                                                                            /var/snap/firefox/common/host-hunspell
  ```